# How to get rid of this sliver of white between DIVs?

Tags: css, html, positioning

I am currently having trouble getting rid of a sliver of white...

Here is an example page: http://m.stackoverflow.quickmediasolutions.com/view_question.php?id=97969&site=serverfault

As you can see, the answers have a sliver of white stuffed between the top of the 'button' and the content.

Here is some relevant code:

```
<!-- this is the top of the 'button' -->
<div class='top'></div>

<!-- right here is where the space is -->
<div class='content'></div>

.top {
    height: 5px;
}
.content {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**Edit:** this problem is fixed now and I will accept the answer below shortly.

Comment: You should probably put this on http://doctype.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like native margin the `<p>` element has:

```
.question p { margin: 0 }
```

A relevant tip here it to use a CSS-Reset, it eliminates most of these oddities and cross-browser compatibility issues.

Comment: I *wondered* if it had something to do with that but really was clueless as to what to do about it - I've had problems like that before :)

Comment: +1 Agreed, its the margin of the paragraph creating the whitespace

Comment: @George If you use *{margin:0;padding:0;} as the first style, then you will only get margin and padding that you specifically apply, which can help you avoid "mystery" whitespace

Comment: @Cez: Great tip... I just might do that.

Answer (score 0):

you know, you'd be surprised how often whitespace breaks layout. I found out the hard way.

Just for $hits and giggles write it out together and see what happens:

```
<div class='top'></div><div class='content'></div>
```

and of course I would make sure that in your css you define `margin:0px;` for both divs